# When forcing a query on a non-interleaved index(s), will there be any data locality benefit?

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Assuming the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Foo (
    primaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    secondaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    extraData STRING(80),
    active BOOL NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (primaryId, secondaryId);

CREATE TABLE Bar (
    primaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    secondaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    barId STRING(64) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (primaryId, secondaryId, barId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Foo ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE Baz (
    primaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    secondaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    barId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    bazId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    extraData STRING(80)
) PRIMARY KEY (primaryId, secondaryId, barId, bazId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Bar ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE INDEX foo_primaryId_active ON foo (primaryId, active);
CREATE INDEX baz_bazId ON Baz (bazId);
```

We have 3 tables *Foo*, *Bar*, *Baz*, where *Bar* is interleaved in *Foo* and *Baz* is interleaved in *Bar*. Along with 2 non-interleaved indexes.

Given the following query where we force the *FROM* and the *JOIN* onto the indexes; no explicit tables.

```sql
SELECT
    baz.primaryId, 
    baz.secondaryId, 
    baz.bazId, 
    baz.extraData
FROM
    Baz@{FORCE_INDEX=baz_bazId} AS baz
JOIN
    Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=foo_secondaryId_isActive} AS foo
ON
    foo.primaryId = baz.parimaryId AND foo.secondaryId = baz.secondaryId
WHERE
    baz.bazId = @bazId -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
    foo.active = true
```

Is there a data locality benefit in this query when forcing the indexes?
If we were to later add a 4th table *Zap* and interleave that table on *Foo*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Zap (
    primaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    secondaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    bazId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    extraData STRING(80)
) PRIMARY KEY (primaryId, secondaryId, bazId),
INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Foo ON DELETE CASCADE;

CREATE INDEX zap_bazId ON Zap (bazId);
```

And adjust the above query to include a 3rd *JOIN*:

```sql
JOIN
    Zap@{FORCE_INDEX=zap_bazId} AS zap
ON 
    zap.bazId = @bazId AND zap.primaryId = foo.primaryId
WHERE
    baz.bazId = @bazId -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
    foo.active = true
    zap.extraData IS NULL
```

Would we obtain any data locality benefit here? Since we are querying on all non-interleaved indexes. Our `zap.extraData IS NULL` predicate is not stored on in the index itself, so that would likely need to run back to the *Zap* table to check.

If there is no data locality benefit from querying on non-interleaved indexes, could we just forgo that extra `zap_bazId` index and just alter the *Zap* table since we know we will be exclusively querying on the *bazId* for the data it hosts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Zap (
    bazId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    primaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    secondaryId STRING(64) NOT NULL,
    extraData STRING(80)
) PRIMARY KEY (bazId, primaryId);
```

the amended query then becomes

```sql
JOIN
    Zap AS zap -- using a table; aka the implicit PRIMARY_KEY index
ON 
    zap.bazId = @bazId AND zap.primaryId = foo.primaryId
WHERE
    baz.bazId = @bazId AND -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
    foo.active = true AND
    zap.extraData IS NULL
```

Now, we lose the CASCADE DELETE here, so it might still just be worth it to interleave and create that additional index and STORING the `zap.extraData` into the index to save it from having to go back to the Zap table to pull that information.

The question would still be: Does data locality even come into play when querying/joining exclusively on non-interleaved indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand from [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/optimizing-schema-design#index-options), if the indexes are not interleaved and you query/join by the indexes, data locality doesn't matter. If you are intending to query using the indexes you should only need to interleave the indexes.

Regardless, as you have explained you can keep using the interleaving on your tables if you are interested in the `ON DELETE CASCADE` statement, as it cannot be done [without interleaving](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#syntax_2).

### Clarifications:

> Given a table with columns `primaryId` and `secondaryId` where the primary key of the table is `primaryId`. Creating a secondary index on `secondaryId` excludes it from being interleaved into the table.

Yes.

> If the indexes are **not** interleaved, **there is no data locality at play**

Depends on the query. Joins between a non-interleaved index and a base table are not local. You should consider the [`STORING`](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/optimizing-schema-design#storing_index_clause) clause in the index to avoid the join. Joins between a table and its parent would be local.

The [query explanation dashboard](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sql-best-practices#how-execute-queries) is a useful tool to show how Cloud Spanner executes specific queries. Using it we can analyze the aforementioned queries.

- There's a distributed join between `baz_bazId` and `Baz` and another distributed join with `foo_primaryId_active`.

  ```
  SELECT
      baz.primaryId,
      baz.secondaryId,
      baz.bazId,
      baz.extraData
  FROM
      Baz@{FORCE_INDEX=baz_bazId} AS baz
  JOIN
      Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=foo_primaryId_active} AS foo
  ON
      foo.primaryId = baz.primaryId AND foo.secondaryId = baz.secondaryId
  WHERE
      baz.bazId = @bazId -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
      AND foo.active = true
  ```

  [image: First query]
- There's an added distributed join between `Zap` and `zap_bazid` which is distributed joined with the rest.

  ```
  SELECT
      baz.primaryId,
      baz.secondaryId,
      baz.bazId,
      baz.extraData
  FROM
      Baz@{FORCE_INDEX=baz_bazId} AS baz
  JOIN
      Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=foo_primaryId_active} AS foo
  ON
      foo.primaryId = baz.primaryId AND foo.secondaryId = baz.secondaryId
  JOIN
      Zap@{FORCE_INDEX=zap_bazId} AS zap
  ON
      zap.bazId = @bazId AND zap.primaryId = foo.primaryId
  WHERE
      baz.bazId = @bazId -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
      AND foo.active = true
      AND zap.extraData IS NULL
  ```

  [image: Second query]
- It uses table `Zap2` (the non-interleaved version of `Zap`) instead of needing the distributed join between `Zap` and `zap_bazid` in the second query.

  ```
  SELECT
      baz.primaryId,
      baz.secondaryId,
      baz.bazId,
      baz.extraData
  FROM
      Baz@{FORCE_INDEX=baz_bazId} AS baz
  JOIN
      Foo@{FORCE_INDEX=foo_primaryId_active} AS foo
  ON
      foo.primaryId = baz.primaryId AND foo.secondaryId = baz.secondaryId
  JOIN
      Zap2 AS zap -- using a table; aka the implicit PRIMARY_KEY index
  ON
      zap.bazId = @bazId AND zap.primaryId = foo.primaryId
  WHERE
      baz.bazId = @bazId AND -- using the baz_bazId index to query on the bazId
      foo.active = true AND
      zap.extraData IS NULL
  ```

  [image: Third query]

> Spanner will handle all the related network I/O re: the data splits.

Yes.

> If indexes **can be** interleaved there would be a benefit but the keys in those interleaved indexes have to be shared (like with any interleaved table). The docs for locality tradeoffs: "Focus on getting the desired locality for the most important root entities and most common access patterns, and let less frequent or less performance sensitive distributed operations happen when they need to."

Yes.

Comment: Just to confirm, as I understand it, to interleave an index it needs to be keyed on the same primary key components as the table it is being interleaved into. So, for example, given a table with columns `primaryId` and `secondaryId` where the primary key of the table is `primaryId`. Creating a secondary index on `secondaryId` excludes it from being interleaved into the table.

Comment: Just another follow up for my own clarification. If the indexes are **not** interleaved, **there is no data locality at play**; Spanner will  handle all the related network I/O re:  the data splits.  If indexes **can be** interleaved there would be a benefit but the keys in those interleaved indexes have to be shared (like with any interleaved table).  The docs for locality tradeoffs: "Focus on getting the desired locality for the most important root entities and most common access patterns, and let less frequent or less performance sensitive distributed operations happen when they need to."

Comment: @AdamVenturella I have updated my answer, check it out for the requested clarifications.